# List.Find() Not returning a value

Tags: c#, list, lambda, predicate

I have a `List<Employee> ListEmployee` and I'm using the following code:

```
public void Func(Contract cont) //the contract have the employee's ID in it
{
    Employee emp = ListEmployees().Find(e => (e.ID_.Equals(cont.EmployeeId_)));
```

The problem is, despite the list having an employee with the same ID as the one in the contract, the `List<>.Find()` returns a null.

Is it a problem with the Lambda expression or something else?

edit:
The `Contract` class has the ID number of an employee of type `int[]` "`cont.EmployeeId_`".
`Employee.ID` is also `int[]` type.

I'm trying to get the Employee from the list that his ID is identical to the one in the contract.

Comment: What is 'cont'?

Comment: Perhaps `e.ID_` and `cont.EmployeeId_` are not of the same type (`"1".Equals(1) == false` and `String.Equals()` accepts `object`).

Comment: Post a *reproducible* example. What is `cont`? What value does it have? Perhaps `ID_` and `EmployeeID_` are strings with trailing whitespaces?

Comment: what are the types of  `Employees.ID_` and `cont.EmployeeId_`

Comment: Not sure why anyone would upvote this question without a [mcve]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. From your code it's not clear what data types of `e.ID_` and `cont.EmployeeID_` and what values these properties have in your case.

Comment: Maybe null==null?  What happens when both items are null?

Comment: As a side note just out of interest - why on earth do your variable names having trailing underscores?

Comment: I'm very sorry about the bad question.
I've edited the question so it will be more understandable.
I'm not used to post questions in this site...

Answer (score 1):

Since the question does not seem to have all the details, maybe instead of using `cont` you meant to use `ctr`

So instead of this:

```
Employee emp = ListEmployees().Find(e => (e.ID_.Equals(cont.EmployeeId_)));
```

you meant this:

```
Employee emp = ListEmployees().Find(e => (e.ID_.Equals(ctr.EmployeeId_)));
```

Comment: the ctr/cont was a typo.
the problem was that for some reason the `equal()` function did not work with the given arguments.
thanks a lot anyway